# Angular Material Dropdown Not Showing Correctly in IE11

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, internet-explorer-11

Is there a way to make IE11 show the Angular Material Dropdown correctly (as all other browsers do)?

**This is how it should look like:**
[image]

**This is how it looks in IE11:**[image]

**This is the website:**
[example no longer available. AngularJS was too slow, we replaced it with a faster technology]

**This is the relevant code of this navigation line (simplified):**

```js
angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="md-block" flex-gt-xs>
    <md-input-container layout="row">
      <div flex>
        <label>Mein Start-Ort (Adresse)</label>
        <inputclass="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div flex="nogrow">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Standort">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="_img/icons/location.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-input-container>
  </div>

  <div class="md-block" layout="row">
    <div flex="nogrow">
      <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Schweiz</md-button>
    </div>
    <md-input-container flex>
      <label>Anreise</label>
      <md-select ng-model="transport">
        <md-option value="car" selected>Mit dem Auto</md-option>
        <md-option value="transit">Mit dem ÖV</md-option>
        <md-option value="bike">Mit dem Velo</md-option>
        <md-option value="walk">Zu Fuss</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: By the way: can anyone tell me why the dropdown opens so slowly in general (all browsers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need flex values on the elements on the right-hand side. Is this like what you're after?

```js
angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div layout="row">
  <div class="md-block" flex-gt-xs>
    <md-input-container layout="row" flex>
      <div flex>
        <label>Mein Start-Ort (Adresse)</label>
        <input class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Standort">
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="_img/icons/location.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-input-container>
  </div>

  <div class="md-block" layout="row">
    <div>
      <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Schweiz</md-button>
    </div>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Anreise</label>
      <md-select ng-model="transport">
        <md-option value="car" selected>Mit dem Auto</md-option>
        <md-option value="transit">Mit dem ÖV</md-option>
        <md-option value="bike">Mit dem Velo</md-option>
        <md-option value="walk">Zu Fuss</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You did it, thank you very much! Just one (bonus) question: do you know why it is so slow to switch tabs or open the dropdown? Do you know how this can be improved?

Comment: I don't. I'm plagued with performance issues in IE myself. If you google for "angular material performance ie", you'll see a whole host of issues regarding this. After sifting through the many issues on their github site, I've had some luck disabling the ripple effect and some css transitions for IE only. Also, make sure you are upgraded to the latest version as I know they did some major fixes for tab performance in one of the versions.

Comment: Hi @adam0101 - thank you for your hint! I just updated the dev.so*** website to angular 1.6.4 and angular material 1.1.4 - but the performance issues still exist (on all browsers on desktop systems, it is only at OK speed on mobile devices) - especially tab switching and dropdown opening is slow. Do you perhaps know a better/faster framework to use?

Comment: @SimonFerndriger, there are several frameworks that use Material Design, but not sure how many work well with Angular. [Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) will have flexbox functionality built in and you can get a Material Design theme for it, but it's still in development. [Here's a list of some others](https://tutorialzine.com/2016/03/the-15-best-material-design-frameworks-and-libraries)

Comment: Thank you very much, @adam0101